# Would continually decreasing your height with Wild Magic Surges eventually make you vanish from existence?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, creature-size, wild-magic

[Wild Magic sorcerers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) (PHB, p. 103-104) have the Wild Magic Surge feature at first level:

> Starting when you choose this origin at 1st level, your spellcasting can unleash surges of untamed magic. Once per turn, the DM can have you roll a d20 immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher. If you roll a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Surge table to create a magical effect. If that effect is a spell, it is too wild to be affected by your Metamagic, and if it normally requires concentration, it doesn’t require concentration in this case; the spell lasts for its full duration.

One of the 50 effects of the Wild Magic Surge table (on a roll of 11–12) is the following:

> Roll a d10. Your height changes by a number of inches equal to the roll. If the roll is odd, you shrink. If the roll is even, you grow.

Let's say that a Wild mage "spams" Wild Magic Surges (with a very Surge-friendly DM who always says "Yes" when there's a possibility for a Surge), and rolls the above effect many, many times, and then always rolls an odd number (height decrease). This can technically cause him to be... 0 feet tall, as there's no written minimum for that Surge.

Compare this to the wording of a similar Surge (on a roll of 35–36):

> Roll a d10. Your age changes by a number of years equal to the roll. If the roll is odd, you get younger ***(minimum 1 year old).*** If the roll is even, you get older.

But on the height change Surge, there's no height minimum written. So... what would happen there? Would the Wild Magic sorcerer vanish from existence?

Of course, this situation has a low chance of happening, considering that if you roughly get every number of a d10 an equal amount of times, you'd have an average decrease of 25 but an average increase of 30 (so a net increase of 5), but it's still possible to be very, very unlucky. For example, the smallest default height a player character can have is 27 inches (by being a kobold and rolling/taking the lowest height modifier), so a few consecutive odd rolls and poof, your height is 0. What now?

Comment: Related: [Can wild magic growth make me a Large creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84010/can-wild-magic-growth-make-me-a-large-creature)

Answer (score 17):

## For the sake of sanity, add a minimum threshold

Things get way too awkward even before zero - at 1 inch (~2.5 cm) and 150 pounds (~68 Kg), the character is now made of something with a stupidly high density. Note that the mass doesn't change with wild magic, so it doesn't vanish - it still has mass. As something can't occupy a zero volume and still have mass, either we completely kill physics to its core (okay we've been doing it already, but this is where I draw the line) or we don't allow it.

If someday this actually happens, I would simply say that, under X inches (possibly around ~15), the wild surge simply doesn't affect the creature any more.

This is not RAW, and it does not need to be. This is a situation that is probably never going to actually happen in a table, so it was probably not thought in advance when making the rules.

> Many unexpected events can occur in a D&D campaign, and no set of rules could reasonably account for every contingency (from XGtE).

Comment: My halfling sorcerer managed to get shrunk to 18 inches tall by this exact situation, and it was starting to get awkward -- not to mention annoying, since he was also blue at that point and it was increasingly feeling like my character wasn't my character any more, at least physically.  I talked it over with the DM and we decided that the height changes could be removed by Remove Curse the same way the blueness could.

Answer (score 4):

No. Mechanically you're fine. Height, including being 0 feet, does not have major penalties per the rules.

> Characters of most races are Medium, a size category including
>   creatures that are roughly 4 to 8 feet tall. Members of a few races
>   are Small (between 2 and 4 feet tall), which means that certain rules
>   of the game affect them differently. The most important of these rules
>   is that Small characters have trouble wielding heavy Weapons, as
>   explained in “Equipment.” ([Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/races))

So, you would probably be some smaller size, if you shrank. Tiny is the smallest size, and the height, or minimum, is left undefined. Being 0 feet has no special mechanical effect in the rules above and beyond being tiny.

[What, approximately, is the size of a tiny creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87721/what-approximately-is-the-size-of-a-tiny-creature)

> Small creatures have disadvantage on Attack rolls with heavy Weapons.
>   A heavy weapon’s size and bulk make it too large for a Small creature
>   to use effectively. (DMG p278)

You can no longer effectively wield heavy weapons.

> Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny creatures can
>   carry less. For each size category above Medium, double the creature’s
>   carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. For a
>   Tiny creature, halve these weights. (PHB p176)

You can't carry much.

> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you, and it must be within your reach. (PBH p195)

And you can't grapple well. You can expect advantage and disadvantage to be a thing with that, at your DM's discretion, say in stealth or weight lifting contests.

Height has no impact on hitpoints or weight or such, and so you'll still weigh say 150 pounds and have however many hitpoints despite having no height, and so will still be around. I'd imagine a very flat sorcerous face wandering around the ground.

That said, mechanically, you're likely to increase in size. 1+3+5+7+9<2+4+6+8+10. So a good way to fix such a problem is more wild magic.

Your DM could decide to house rule it otherwise, and it's worth asking them if they have any intended house rules for small and tiny creatures.

Comment: This does not address the question at all - it asks about what happens if you reach 0 ft tallness, and if that's possible.

Comment: Mechanically, certainly, and there are rules for what happens at certain heights. None of those rules say "You die."

Comment: You seem to assume that the creature reduces its size category when they lose height. Do you have any logic or rules support for this? Answers to other questions seem divided. For example, [Can wild magic growth make me a Large creature?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84010). If the rules do say this, at what heights would you be considered each size?

Comment: I'll add that in. https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/races This covers that.

Comment: @NepeneNep Again: what about 0? The answer itself does not address it. The question is not about what happens when you simply reduce size or what happens when you are small or tiny, it's what happens if you reach **zero** tallness. A "very flat" is still not 0 - only a bidimensional object could have zero tallness, and effectively that doesn't exist in our world.

Comment: Is there some reason why you see 0 feet as some sort of important height to have, RAW? Do the rules forbid being bidimensional objects as a result of wild magic somewhere?

Comment: @NepeneNep: It's important because it's literally the specific amount that the question is about; the question is asking what happens to your character if your height is reduced to 0, specifically. If you believe that the answer is "nothing different from when your height is any more than that", then that should be clearly noted in your answer.

Comment: I edited in that being 0 feet has no special mechanical impact beyond you being tiny.